# MySQL convert date to age in a Select Statement

Tags: mysql, date, select

I'm using the following Select Statement to get a users birthdate and other info. I wanted to see if I could get the date converted to an age in the returned data - rather then convert it in PHP.

Date format in Database is: 1979-04-26

```
SELECT profile_username,profile_gender,profile_birthdate FROM loginTable WHERE id=1000;
```

Current return is like

```
Adam,Male,1979-04-26
```

Can I get back:

```
Adam,Male,34
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT profile_username,profile_gender,
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(profile_birthdate, '%Y') - 
(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(profile_birthdate, '00-%m-%d')) 
AS age
FROM loginTable WHERE id=1000;
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02ef07/8)**